# Sync command wont update values

Tags: laravel

Hello i have this code in `Laravel` that updates existing `many-to-many` relationship tables so when i use the `sync` command the values update wrong, this is the code:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $order = Order::where('id', $id)->first();

    $request->validate([
        'order_number' => 'required',
        'client_id' => 'required',
        'description' => 'required',
        'productOrder' => 'required',
        'productOrder.*.product_id' => 'required|distinct|exists:products,id',
        'productOrder.*.amount' => 'required|numeric|min:1',
    ]);

    $order->update($request->all());

    foreach ($request->productOrder as $product) {

        $values[] = [
            'order_id' => $order->id,
            'product_id' => $product['product_id'],
            'amount' => $product['amount'],
        ];

        $amount = Product::find($product['product_id']);

        $totalValue = $product['amount'] + $amount->amount;

        $amount->update(['amount' => $totalValue]);
    }
    
    $order->products()->sync($values); //the problem is here

    $orders = Order::all();

    $orders->load('client', 'products');

    return view('orders/index', compact('orders'));
}
```

If i have 2 values like:

```
Product1 -> amount: 250

Product2 -> 100
```

And i updatet these existing values to

```
 Product1 -> amount: 350

 Product2 -> 200
```

The result will be

```
Product2 -> 200

Product2 -> 200
```

If i make this line of code  `dd($order->products()->sync($values));` i get this result

[image]

If i add a new product with the existing ones i get this result

[image]

From what im understanding the first result is replaced with the second one or removed, why does this happen?

Comment: Sync does not work as you expect, `sync` literally expects an array of ids, so you passing an array of string indexes and values, will just not work... Sync literally expects an array of ids and if you want to change something from that ID (another column), you put the ID as an index, and the value an array of columns to change to... Read how [`sync` works](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#syncing-associations) again please. One more thing, doing `Order::where('id', $id)->first()` is exactly the same as `Order:find($id)`... And first validate, then do whatever you want

Comment: @matiaslauriti i read about `sync` but its confusing you say it needs an id so to change values i need ID as index and value  i did something like this but makes error `$order->products()->sync([$product['product_id'] => ['amount' => true], $product['amount']]);`

Comment: @matiaslauriti this code is inside a foreach so the value changes of the amount and product id

Comment: What is `$product['amount']`? You are passing an amount value as an ID... did you mean this? `$order->products()->sync([$product['product_id'] => ['amount' => $product['amount']]]);`

Comment: `$product['amount']` has the amount for each `product_id`

Comment: so, it must go inside the array that has `$product['product_id']` as index and must have `'amount' => $product['amount']`

Comment: yes correct the `product_id` is the index but the `product_id` with the `amount` must both be updated also

Comment: I mean, read the documentation link again, it is pretty self explanatory, as my previous comments

Comment: the document doesnt says to do what i want to achieve i dont want the existing values to be deleted i want them to be replaced or add new values. What sync does is remove the existing one and insert new

Comment: I am going to say _"read the documentation"_ again, it is very important that you learn how to read documentation (specially that of Laravel, it is superb). If you can't master that, you are going to learn nothing and just struggle everytime as a developer. So, if you [read the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#attaching-detaching), just A section above `sync`, you will see you have `attach` and `detach` available. If you just want to update, you have to manually update each

Comment: @matiaslauriti as i said before i have read the documentation you arent understanding my question. Now i believe you are familiar with the function update meaning if you modify existing values and add new ones they will be saved with no problem ` $amount->update(['amount' => $totalValue]);` but when i use sync meaning i have [1,2,3] and i send an array with [1,2,3,4] the existing ID will delete and add the new ones only. So i found that this function is done if i use `detach` first then `attach` and my question is, *Is there any function that works the same as `update`?*

Comment: I truly am not sure, but, if you read the documentation, AGAIN (don't get mad please), you will see you can use `syncWithoutDetaching`, it is in the same section as `sync`, just a little bit down... I have never used `syncWithoutDetaching` to update, maybe it will work, try it out! (Just in case, `syncWithoutDetaching` will sync but NOT remove the missing IDs from the DB, so that may be what you want)

Comment: @matiaslauriti and instead of pushing over and over the same thing `read documentation` when i keep saying i have done so you could have given me an answer but i got the answer at `Laracast` and i got this : `Oh sorry I do really understand your question only right now : no there is no solution to do both things with one unique method.` If you disagree here is the url to the post to add your answer: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/how-to-use-sync-eloquent-method

Comment: @matiaslauriti yes it wont remove it but i also need to remove it just a simple update [1,2,3,4] lets say i remove 1 and post [2,3,4] but then i want to add 1 and 5 so i send [1,2,3,4,5]. Thats all what i mean because i tried both `sync` and `syncWithoutDetaching` and it does not do what i wanted

Comment: You can see how long the thread here is and in Laracast is even longer, so you were not correctly communicating what you want. I read it twice, and I still don't understand what you want... `detach`ing and then `attach`ing is the equivalent of `sync`... sync will detach any ID you did not pass, and add or update the existing ones... when you call `$order->products()->detach();` and then `$order->products()->attach([...]);` that is literally doing `$order->products()->sync([...]);`, so I do not understand what you don't understand

Comment: If you want to remove EVERYTHING and then only add the ones you want, `sync`. If you want to delete EVERYTHING and then only add the ones you want, but then (I do not know why) you want to add one that got deleted, THEN use `syncWithoutDetaching`... but that logic is not right, why are you deleting and then adding, and then adding again? that is the part that makes no sense and no one understands. That is why no one but me is trying to help you here, no one understands what you want because makes no sense

Comment: @matiaslauriti here is the update form https://ibb.co/6H80kgX the values product and amount are from database meaning they exist, if i want to add another third value lets say 3 in database i should have [1,2,3] correct? But if i edit again and this time i delete the first product and amount with that minus button on its side and click save i should have [2,3] only correct? whell `sync` is not doing this and also `syncWithoutDetaching` is not doing this

Comment: If that is not working with `sync` that is another issue, but you should be using `sync` in this case, because you only want to leave or update the stuff you got back, in this case 2 and 3, and remove 1 because you clicked `-`. If `sync` is not syncing, then it is because you are not using the right `id` as index, because you also want to update the `amount`, in that case is `$order->products()->sync([2 => ['amount' => $product['amount']], 3 => ['amount' => $product2['amoun']]);`, your issue is that you are running `sync` in a loop, that is wrong, the array must already have EVERYTHING set

Comment: Let me add an answer because I think I DO understand now

Comment: @matiaslauriti here is a link of screen record what i mean ,the code works fine now because i do first `detach` then `attach` https://streamable.com/v7gsey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you have this code:

```php
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $order = Order::where('id', $id)->first();

    $request->validate([
        'order_number' => 'required',
        'client_id' => 'required',
        'description' => 'required',
        'productOrder' => 'required',
        'productOrder.*.product_id' => 'required|distinct|exists:products,id',
        'productOrder.*.amount' => 'required|numeric|min:1',
    ]);

    $order->update($request->all());

    foreach ($request->productOrder as $product) {

        $values[] = [
            'order_id' => $order->id,
            'product_id' => $product['product_id'],
            'amount' => $product['amount'],
        ];

        $amount = Product::find($product['product_id']);

        $totalValue = $product['amount'] + $amount->amount;

        $amount->update(['amount' => $totalValue]);
    }
    
    $order->products()->sync($values); //the problem is here

    $orders = Order::all();

    $orders->load('client', 'products');

    return view('orders/index', compact('orders'));
}
```

The issue with it, is that `sync` is getting wrong IDs, because `$values` has numeric autoincrementals IDs: `0`, `1`, `2`, etc.

What you need to pass to the `sync` is either an array of IDs `[1, 2, 3]`, or an array of arrays (when you want to update columns related to that ID, for example: `[1 => ['amount' => 100], 2, 3]`.

Let me try to modify your code to help you.

Let's assume you `orders` table and `products` table. You also have a pivot table called `order_product` table, so you store the relation in there. This `order_product` table has:

- `id`
- `order_id`
- `product_id`
- `amount`

So, your code should be like this:

```php
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $validated = $request->validate([
        'order_number' => 'required',
        'client_id' => 'required',
        'description' => 'required',
        'productOrder' => 'required',
        'productOrder.*.product_id' => 'required|distinct|exists:products,id',
        'productOrder.*.amount' => 'required|numeric|min:1',
    ]);

    $order = Order::find($id); // I would change this to use implicit binding

    $order->update($validated); // Don't use $request->all(), you are using unvalidated values

    foreach ($request->productOrder as $product) {

        $values[$product['product_id']] = [
            'amount' => $product['amount']
        ];

        $amount = Product::find($product['product_id']);

        $totalValue = $product['amount'] + $amount->amount;

        $amount->update(['amount' => $totalValue]);
    }
    
    $order->products()->sync($values); // Now it will work

    $orders = Order::all();

    $orders->load('client', 'products');

    return view('orders/index', compact('orders'));
}
```